# Calculating cumulant from data set

Tags: statistics

Given a data set $x = \{ x(n) \mid n=1,\ldots,m\}$ how do I calculate the $p^{th}$-order cumulant? In particular I need to calculate the 4th-order cumulant. I found that I can calculate the cumulant from moments, but I also don't know how to calculate moments. I found how to calculate the 4th central moment (kurtosis) but I am not sure if/how they are related.

Since I have to implement the calculation of the cumulant in C++ I would be interested in a general explanation (to understand what I am doing) but also hints on how to implement the calculation efficiently would be appreciated. How can one interpret the 4th-order cumulant?

I am sorry if this is a trivial question but I don't have a strong mathematical background and was not able to find the answer online.

Comment: Is the "$p$" in "$n=1,\cdots,p$" the same as the "$p$" in "$p^\text{th}$-order"?

Comment: No, it is not the same. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the cumulants using the following recursion formula :
http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/9/b/2/9b2b9e42c18cd141a6236fa04b6715a5.png where the $\kappa$ are the cumulants and the $m$ are the moments.

The $p$-th order moment is given by
$$m_p=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^p$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it and accept your answer. Since the image you linked to is from wikimedia, is there a corresponding article where the image is used? Could you provide the link to it?

Comment: Sure, it's from the Cumulants page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant